# Tweepy is not fetching all of the Tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets

This is the trending topic on Twitter right now

```
#PakistanReject_Israel
```

With more than 47K Tweets. But When I try to scrape the tweets via Tweepy, it is only getting 948 Tweets. and `Process finished with exit code 0`

Is there any problem with my code or any limitation from Tweepy? While with the same code I have scraped more than 60K Tweets in one run, with another search query.

[image]

Here is the code

```
max_tweets = 200000
filname= createtime+"PakistanReject_Israel"
text_query = ('#PakistanReject_Israel')
date_since= "2020-11-20"
jsonFile = open(filname+'.json', "a",encoding='utf-8')
try:
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=text_query,lang="en",since=date_since,tweet_mode='extended').items(max_tweets): #,lang="en"
        json_str = json.dumps(tweet._json, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        jsonFile.write(json_str)
except ConnectionError as e:
    print("Some Problem happened %s Tweets are fetched" % count)
    print(e)
finally:
    jsonFile.close()
```

Comment: The legacy Twitter standard search API supports a maximum of 100 Tweets per request, and a maximum of 180 requests in a 15 minute period, which is 18,000 Tweets you could do in that period. The other thing to note is that the standard search API is only a partial index, so not every Tweet will be returned. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

Comment: how do we count requests? if i want to set limit on requests?

Comment: You will have to set up a counter in your code to increment each time you call the API.